# Should the tags "sentence-structures" and "syntax" be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I think [syntax](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax) is the technical and linguistic term for the more popular [sentence-structures](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-structures) tag used here. [The Wikipedia article on syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax) seems to verify this:

> In linguistics, syntax ... is the study of the principles and rules for constructing sentences in natural languages. In addition to referring to the discipline, the term syntax is also used to refer directly to the rules and principles that govern the sentence structure of any individual language, ...

So please vote to merge or clarify what should separate them